# AngularJS. Filter array by array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have data structure like this:

```
$scope.data = [
  {
    title: "Title1",
    countries: ['USA', 'Canada', 'Russia']
  },
  {
    title: "Title2",
    countries: ['France', 'Germany']
  }
];
```

I.e. each item has array of country names.

I'm showing this data like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="dataItem in data">
```

I want allow user to filter this list by providing list of countries in input:

[image]

How to acheive this?

Currently I'm did something like this:

```
  <input ng-model="searchFilter.countries">
   ...
  <tr ng-repeat="dataItem in data | filter: searchFilter: true">
```

But obviously it works only for 1 country, not for array of countries listed in input using comma.

Comment: It would be much easier if you create a JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dfed4/6/).

It takes use of `ngList` as Zahori recommended and defines a custom filter for countries.

```
myApp.filter('MyFilter', function() {
    return function(items, countries) {
        if (!angular.isUndefined(items) && !angular.isUndefined(countries) && countries.length > 0) {
            var filtered = [];

            angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
                angular.forEach(countries, function(currentCountry) {
                     if(item.countries.indexOf(currentCountry) >= 0 ) filtered.push(item);
                });

            });

            return filtered;
        } else {
            return items;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution, without a custom filter:

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="countries" ng-list>

<tr ng-repeat="dataItem in data | filter:countryFilter">
```

JS:

```
$scope.countryFilter = function(dataItem) {
    if (!$scope.countries || $scope.countries.length < 1)
        return true;
    var matched = false;
    $scope.countries.filter(function(n) {
        matched = matched || dataItem.countries.indexOf(n) != -1
    });
    return matched;
};
```

**[DEMO PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/E6jokaw6uoZjPfuqoQDp?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Your Input is just a String and not an Array. You can use ngList for this purpose.

Here is a good example how to use it:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList

Answer (score 0):

searchFilter should be a method on your $scope. Otherwise by default it searches on string only.

```
$scope.searchFilter = function (dataItem) {
    //your search logic here and return true/false.
};
```